# Is there any way to set location for PC windows 10

Tags: windows-10

As most PC I do not have GPS on my PC. But then again, it's not like my PC needs GPS in a sense that it's not moving anywhere anyway. I can pin point where it is on the map.

I have no idea if it has uses at all though. I am just curious. I mean windows 10 is like windows phone. So how to set location?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, but you could try this method.
http://www.howtogeek.com/264809/how-to-set-your-default-location-for-windows-10-apps/

Answer (score 1):

To set a default location

1. Click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2. Search for location in search box and then click Enter a default location.
3. Enter a postal code. If you want to provide an address, you can enter it under Enter an address (optional).
4. Click Apply.`Administrator` permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

more details and reference at: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/set-a-geographic-location-for-your-computer

windows 10: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/change-the-default-location-reported-in-windows-10/a5f5a0f9-2b21-4658-9b92-97519667be06

Comment: I did that and search location. Nothing like set default location show up. I can set region and I set that to US. That seems to handle language and format.

Comment: You need to go through `location privacy settings`.

Comment: No such option on my WIndows 10 install. Also, the Maps app does not seem to be installed, and the Windows 10 App Store seems unavailable (even with my administrator account) due to AppLocker related policy settings. So I'm only shown a message box "You'll need a new app to open this ms-default-location" when I click the "Set default" button in "Location privacy settings", without any way to actually set a default location anywhere. Are there registry settings? Some ini-file? A PowerShell module/cmdlet?